# How to make searche in Room database

Tags: android, android-room

I have a Room database has some data from retrofit and i create search in this base, but this method search and work when i write full title (not words).
For example i want search **Uganda** and my app cant found data than has **Uganda**. But when i write Uganda: 500 Cows Die Due to Drought" (its full title), my app founds article.

Its my DAO and code than i use for search

```
//DAO
@Dao
public interface NewsDao {
@Query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE title LIKE :search OR content LIKE :search OR publishedAt LIKE :search ")
    List<News> searchInDatabase(String search);
}

// part of code than searchs 

@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (newText != null && !newText.isEmpty()) {
            newsAfterSearch = newsDao.searchInDatabase(newText);
            displayData(newsAfterSearch);


        } else displayData(news);

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: When you use `LIKE`, you need to use wildcards. `search` would need to be `Uganda%`. See [the SQLite documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE` in your queries:

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE column LIKE pattern;
```

eg. Select all customers with a name starting with `a`:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%';
```

And in your case, something like (selects all customers with a CustomerName that have "or" in any position) :

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%or%';
```

Ref: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)